# Amanogawa cherry branches are floppy

Tags: trees, cherries

I have an amanogawa cherry tree which I planted a year ago.  It's been under attack from aphids and ants and we have been having some extremely hot weather.   A couple of its branches are extremely floppy when this type of tree is supposed to have an upright growing habit.  Do you think this is because the tree has been under stress or do I need to prune?  When is the best time to do this?

Comment: Hi, welcome! Could you [edit] your post with a picture, please? While you wait for answers, I recommend you take the [tour] and browse our [help] to learn more about how the site and the Stack Exchange network works. Oh, and using ALL CAPS is considered “yelling” in Internet speak - normal spelling is perfect fine. Within the posts, you can also use the formatting functions if you need to emphasize something specific.